# "How're you supposed to get one on their own to ask them?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Why do they have to move in packs?" Harry asked Ron as a dozen or so girls walked past them, sniggering and staring at Harry. **"How're you supposed to get one on their own to ask them?"**
>
>
> "Lasso one?" Ron suggested. "Got any idea who you're going to try?"
>
>
> Harry didn't answer. He knew perfectly well whom he'd like to ask, but working up the nerve was something else ... Cho was a year older than he was; she was very pretty; she was a very good Quidditch player, and she was also very popular. (22.28-30)

Could you explain what the bold sentence means in this context? I assume Harry asked how Ron was going to find his partner among the girls but don't understand how this sentence expresses that meaning. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harry means to ask this: I want to speak privately to a girl, but when I see girls they are always in groups. How am I supposed to find a girl when she is alone, or persuade her to leave the group with me, so that I can ask her something in private?

Perhaps this expression is a little more confusing because in the first sentence Harry used the words "their" and "them," as singular words, although they are usually plural. He could have more grammatically said "How're you supposed to get one on her own to ask her?"

By the way, I have not read these books, but I have the impression (from life with my kids) that Harry is thinking of asking a girl to the dance. That is, he is thinking of inviting a girl to the dance. And he does not want to be observed, perhaps to avoid embarrassment to himself or his invitee.